# PDO execute in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Iam having some trouble with a PDO execute statement. My code looks like this:

```
try {

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO smtp_servers (host, port, ssl, auth, username, password) VALUES(:host, :port, :ssl, :auth, :username, :password)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':host', $serverOptions[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':port', $serverOptions[1]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssl', $serverOptions[2]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':auth', $serverOptions[3]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $serverOptions[4]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $serverOptions[5]);
    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print("fail");
}
```

It dosen't print "fail" if i make a print before the `$stmt->execute();` it prints the test, but if i make a print just after the execute line, it dosen't print the text.

Any ideas?

**UPDATED:**

I tried to throw the more generic Exception, without any luck, i implemented `PDO::PARAM_INT` where i am using integers. And also added the line:

```
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now my code looks like this:

```
try {

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO smtp_servers (host, port, ssl, auth, username, password) VALUES(:host, :port, :ssl, :auth, :username, :password)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':host', $serverOptions[0]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':port', $serverOptions[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssl', $serverOptions[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':auth', $serverOptions[3], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $serverOptions[4]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $serverOptions[5]);
    $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    debug("fail");
}
```

I quess it would help to see my db table design?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `smtp_servers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `port` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ssl` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auth` smallint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now i am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssl, auth, username, password FROM smtp_servers' at line 1' in /var/www/isms/php/communication/Mail.php on line 13 PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssl, auth, username, password FROM smtp_servers' at line 1 in /var/www/isms/php/communication/Mail.php on line 13 Call Stack: 0.0002 649056 1. {main}() /var/www/isms/index.php:0 0.0023 867336 2. include('/var/www/isms/php/settings/ismsSettings.php') /var/www/isms/index.php:88 0.0065 1091712 3. require_once('/var/www/isms/php/settings/MailSettings.php') /var/www/isms/php/settings/ismsSettings.php:29 0.0147 2288960 4. require_once('/var/www/isms/php/forms/settings/EditSmtpServer.php') /var/www/isms/php/settings/MailSettings.php:4 0.0155 2290456 5. Mail->getServers() /var/www/isms/php/forms/settings/EditSmtpServer.php:41 0.0156 2291888 6. PDOStatement->execute() /var/www/isms/php/communication/Mail.php:13

Comment: Try changing the exception to the generic `Exception`. PDO should be throwing a PDOException, but maybe there is a different exception being thrown somehow.

Comment: Also, are all your fields strings? The third parameter to bindParam is  data_type, which defaults to PDO::PARAM_STR. You may need PDO::PARAM_INT or something else.

Comment: The error message is peculiar - especially this part: `'ssl, auth, username, password FROM smtp_servers'`. This looks like SELECT syntax, which is not what you are doing here. Did a SELECT fail earlier, and somehow it's not throwing the Exception until the code you've posted. What is at ` /var/www/isms/php/communication/Mail.php on line 13`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With addition to andrewsi's comment about "[MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)"...
[ssl is indeed a MySQL reserved word!]

As it stands your create table statement also fails as is, but formatted like so; does not

```
CREATE TABLE `smtp_servers` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`host` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`port` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`ssl` SMALLINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`auth` SMALLINT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

### Although, as I've been writing this I notice that `StackOverflow` uses the [spacing grave](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm)  for formatting! ( ` )(&#096)

So, in conclusion change your prepare statement line to the following:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `smtp_servers` 
    (`host`, `port`, `ssl`, `auth`, `username`, `password`) 
    VALUES(:host, :port, :ssl, :auth, :username, :password)");
```

**Note :** *only formatted this way for easier reading* :)

Comment: The sql create statement is taken directly from a mysql export file, so i guess its ok? I'll give it a try with your statement, when i come home.

Comment: I tried without ssl in the queiry and now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: just to note, if you do use those characters around your column names you can still use the column \`ssl\` :) Glad you have it sorted and good luck with your work

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the `fail` print should only happen in case of a problem, when an Exception is thrown by the script inside the try block.

Assuming everything went smooth and the query succeeded, not seeing the line is a good sign.

---

If the query has not succeeded, and yet you are still not seeing the error message, try telling PDO to only throw PDOExceptions on errors:

```
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Right after instantiating the PDO object.

Comment: @Mathias: Here's a stupid question: Does the query work? When you look at the database, is it changed?

Comment: No the database isn't updated, sorry if i wasn't clear about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the SQL of the query, replacing the named parameters with the actual parameters you're trying to insert, and running it from the command line?

The text of the exception implies that there's a problem with the SQL statement, rather than with the PDO connection, and running it from the command line will let you know if the SQL itself works.

Comment: You are right about that, the commandline also fails (with the same input as i try using at the website):


mysql> INSERT INTO smtp_servers (host, port, ssl, auth, username, password) VALUES("hostname", 123, "1", "1", "user", "HKJ");ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssl, auth, username, password) VALUES("hostname", 123, "1", "1", "user", "HKJ")' at line 1
mysql>

Comment: Those should be single quotes not double.

Comment: I'm wondering if one of your field names is an SQL reserved word - it looks like the database is complaining about either the column 'port' or 'ssl' in the first part of the INSERT. Can you try the INSERT from the command line again, without the port column and its data, and then without ssl, if the first one works?

Comment: I'll give it a try when i come home. But shouldn't MySQL have complained when i created the table, if its a reserved word?

Comment: That's a good point - I rather thought it would have. I've just tried to create a table with fields called port and ssl, and I'm unable to create it when there's a field called ssl in there. This is in PHP 5.1.61; there's a chance that there's a typo in my SQL, though, as I've not yet had any coffee...

Comment: I tried without ssl in the queiry and now it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are in a particular namespace right now. Try replacing `} catch (PDOException $e) {` with `} catch (\PDOException $e) {` and see if something changes.

Comment: @Mathias, are you sure you added `$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`? I don't see it...

Comment: It's because iam connecting to mysql (and instantiating the PDO) in another class which iam extending in this file.

Comment: Could you copy the connection and all the stuff?